# shared folder for a docker container

Tags: docker

It is certainly a basic question but I don't know how to deal with this issue.

I am creating a simple docker image executing Python scripts and which be deployed on differents users's Windows laptops. It needs specific shared folder in order to write outputs at the end of the process.
Users are not able to manage any informatic stuff like docker or simple terminal.
So they run it with a bat file where I indicate the docker command with -v option.
But obviously users path are differents on each laptop. How to create a standard image which could avoid this specific mounting path
thanks a lot

Comment: Please update your post to give some examples of the paths you need to support

Comment: The `AppData` folder is usually the place to store program-specific data. You can get the folder from `APPDATA` env variable.

Comment: for instance:      docker run --rm -ti  -v C:\Users\homeUser1\Desktop\workFolderUser1\output:/dockerFolder/output myContainer python3 dockerFolder/bin/runProcess.py   but for a user2 it is different

Comment: How is it different for user2? You're asking us to figure out the pattern in the directories your users will be using. If there is no pattern then there is no other option than having your users input the path.

Comment: could mounting the remote location in the script be an option? you just request admin privileges and map it as needed then get the drive location and letter

Comment: Yes Hans you are right ... I agree but I thought a solution could exist to figure out this. For user1 it could be on Desktop while on user2 it could be in Documents folder Thanks